# Пароль не регистрируется при сохранении нового пользователя в Django с пользовательской моделью пользователя

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-model, регистрация

Когда я пытаюсь зарегистрировать пользователя, адаптируя то, что я узнал из [Building a Custom User Model with Extended Fields youtube tutorial](https://youtu.be/Ae7nc1EGv-A?t=2029), я не могу войти в систему после этого, несмотря на предоставление того же пароля. Однако я могу войти в систему для любого созданного мной пользователя через командную строку. Вот часть `views.py`, которая занимается регистрацией пользователей:

`views.py`

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, get_object_or_404
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, AuthenticationForm
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.conf import settings
User = settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL
from django.db import IntegrityError
from django.contrib.auth import login, logout, authenticate
from .forms import TodoForm
from .models import Todo
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

def home(request):
    return render(request, 'todo/home.html')

def signupuser(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render(request, 'todo/signupuser.html', {'form':UserCreationForm()})
    else:
        if request.POST['password1'] == request.POST['password2']:
            try:
                db = get_user_model()
                user = db.objects.create_user(request.POST['email'], request.POST['username'], 
                                            request.POST['firstname'], request.POST['company'], request.POST['mobile_number'], 
                                            password=request.POST['password1'])
                user.save()
                login(request, user)
                return redirect('currenttodos')
```

Пользователь по-прежнему зарегистрирован, но я не могу войти в систему с предоставленным паролем, я не попадаю в currenttodos для всех, кроме пользователя, которого я создал через командную строку ... В чем может быть причина?

Вот моя пользовательская модель пользователя:

`models.py`:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin, BaseUserManager


class CustomAccountManager(BaseUserManager):

    def create_superuser(self, email, user_name, first_name, password, **other_fields):

        other_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        other_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)
        other_fields.setdefault('is_active', True)

        if other_fields.get('is_staff') is not True:
            raise ValueError(
                'Superuser must be assigned to is_staff=True.')
        if other_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
            raise ValueError(
                'Superuser must be assigned to is_superuser=True.')

        return self.create_user(email, user_name, first_name, password, **other_fields)

    def create_user(self, email, user_name, first_name,  company, mobile_number, password, **other_fields):

        if not email:
            raise ValueError(('You must provide an email address'))

        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, user_name=user_name, first_name=first_name, 
                        company=company, mobile_number=mobile_number, password=password, **other_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        return user

class Newuser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(('email address'), unique=True)
    user_name = models.CharField(max_length=150, unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True)
    mobile_number = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    company = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects = CustomAccountManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['user_name', 'first_name', 'mobile_number']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user_name
```

`settings.py`

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'todo.NewUser'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если честно как-то все путано. Может я что не понимаю, но может проще сделать.

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    mobile_number = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    company = models.CharField(max_length=5)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

**Forms**

```
class UserRegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ("username", 'first_name', 'last_name', "email", "password1", "password2", "mobile_number", "company")
    

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(UserRegistrationForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.email = self.cleaned_data['email']
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user
```

Views

```
def register_request(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = UserRegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            login(request, user)
            messages.success(request, "Регистрация прошла успешно!" )
            return redirect("homepage")
        messages.error(request, "Регистрация не удалась. Проверьти правильность заполнения формы")
    form = UserRegistrationForm()
    return render (request=request, template_name="accounts/register.html", context={"register_form":form})

def login_request(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = AuthenticationForm(request, data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            if user is not None:
                login(request, user)
                messages.info(request, f"Вы вошли как {username}.")
                return redirect("homepage")
            else:
                messages.error(request,"Неверное имя пользователя или пароль!")
        else:
            messages.error(request,"Неверное имя пользователя или пароль!")
    form = AuthenticationForm()
    return render(request=request, template_name="accounts/login.html", context={"login_form":form})
```

**Login template**

```
{% extends "auth_base.html" %}
{% block content %}      

{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

<!--Login--> 
<div class="container py-5">
  <h1>Вход</h1>
  <form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ login_form|crispy }}
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Войти</button>
  </form>
  <p class="text-center">Не зарегестрированы? <a href="{% url 'auth:register' %}">Создать аккаунт</a>.</p>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

**Register Template**

```
{% extends "auth_base.html" %}

{% block content %} 

{% load crispy_forms_tags %}         

<!--Register--> 
<div class="container py-5">
    <h1>Регистрация</h1>
    <form method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ register_form|crispy }}                    
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Зарегестрироваться</button>
    </form>
    <p class="text-center">Если вы уже зарегистрированы, то <a href="/login">войдите</a></p>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```